# Проблема с модулем nrf24l01, на всех каналах видит шум (arduino)

Tags: c++, arduino

у меня проблема с модулем nrf24l01 на всех каналах есть шум, как на фото:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Раньше пробовал с этим же модулем, все работало.
Не знаю в чем дело, все подключено по схеме из инета, код тоже из инета.
Помогите, плиз.

Answer (score 0):

У вас не шум видит, а проблема аппаратной части. Скорее всего, с подключением модуля. Проверьте как подключены пины IRQ и CS в программе и физически на плате. Есть второй вариант, что модуль поврежден и по этому выдает такое, но это маловероятно.